# Блоки div сливаются в одно

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый вечер.
Сейчас верстаю одну страницу и мне нужно выровнять блоки в одну строку, использую я для этого float: left;
Все бы хорошо, но у меня блоки сливаются из-за того, что я ранее использовал float:left для ul, li. Но, почему они сливаются? Вроде бы я даже вынес их в отдельный блок div.

CSS и HTML:

```css
@import url(reset.css);

@font-face {
    font-family: PTSans NarrowBold; /* Имя шрифта */
    src: url(../font/pt-sans-narrow-bold.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
   }

body{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: url(../img/price-background.png);
}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 background-color: #000000;
}

.top-menu-list{
 height: 70px;
 width: 940px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-menu-list ul li{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: 45px;
 font-family: PTSans NarrowBold;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.top-menu-list ul{
 padding-top: 29px;
 padding-left: 20px;
}

.top-menu-list .menu-exit {
 float: right;
 background: url(../img/enter.png) no-repeat;
}

.top-menu-list .menu-exit a{
 padding-left: 25px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.top-menu-list a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.top-menu-list a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}

main{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 940px;
 height: 795px;
}

.mini-menu{
 height: 63px;
 padding-top: 59px;
 font-family: PTSans NarrowBold;
 color: #000000;
}

.mini-menu h1{
 font-size: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 29px;
}

.mini-menu ul li{
 float: left;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.mini-menu a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}

.mini-menu a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.mini-menu .price-li{
 list-style-image: url(../img/price-rhomb.png);
 margin-left: 35px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.title-main .line-left{
 margin-top: 79px;
 background: url(../img/price-line.png) no-repeat;
 width: 160px;
 height: 2px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 float:left;
}

.title-main h2{
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Price</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/price.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/log.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="top-menu-list">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Информация</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Прайс-лист</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="menu-exit"><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Вход</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main role="main">
  <div class="mini-menu">
   <h1>Barbershop Borodinski - Прайс-лист</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="price-li"><a href="#">Прайс-лист</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div class="title-main">
   <div class="line-left"></div>
   <h2>Истинно мужская классика</h2>
   <div class="line-right"></div>
  </div>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .mini-menu:after{display: table; clear:both; content:' ';} вот такую конструкцию используй и дай тому блоку после, которого начинается новый блок с float:left, если я правильно к этому блоку добавил или к какому нужно

Comment: Что-то не срабатывает... :(

Comment: к каким блокам есть вопросы?

Comment: От main и ниже.

Comment: попробуй дать оболочке с float'om  display:table; clear:both; без after, а то у тебя там половина вываливается

Comment: Спасибо!
Последний совет помог

Comment: В следующий раз постарайся объяснять причину или описывать вопрос более детальнее, гораздо быстрее можно будет решить его

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй дать оболочке с `float`'om `display:table; clear:both;` и такую конструкцию `:after{display: table; clear:both; content:' ';}` , если нужно очистить обтекания.